# Issue doing parameter encoding with Alamofire 4.0

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to convert a code base for Swift 3.0 Currently using

```
return (Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: nil).0, uploadData)
```

Where:

```
let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
```

Have the error `"ParameterEncoding has no member URL"`. Also tried

```
return (Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.encode(mutableURLRequest).0, uploadData) and the doesn't work. Any ideas how to fix this? Any pointers would be really appreciated! Thanks!
```

Comment: Hello @Kex if you solved this problem please post your answer.

Comment: @kex have same issue. can you please post your answer. I'm stuck

Answer (score 3):

Alamofire has a struct URLEncoding, which confirms to the ParameterEncoding protocol.

```
    var urlRequest:URLRequest? = nil
    do {
        try   urlRequest =  Alamofire.URLEncoding().encode(mutableURLRequest, with: parameters)
    } catch {

    }
    return urlRequest!
```